# Blender error : 'tuple' object has no attribute 'clear'

Tags: python, scripting

I'm implementing a UIList and I need to register a PropertyGroup variable in the Scene. I made a custom PropertyGroup

```
class LayerTreeNode(PropertyGroup):
    name: ""
    selfIndex : IntProperty(default=-1)
    parentIndex: IntProperty(default=-1)
    childCount : IntProperty(default=0)
  
class LayerTreeItem(PropertyGroup):
    indent : IntProperty(default=0)
    expanded : BoolProperty(default=False)
    nodeIndex : IntProperty(default=-1)
    childCount : IntProperty(default=0)
```

and my `register()` looks like below

```
def register():
for cls in classes:
    bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

bpy.types.Scene.layerListNode = CollectionProperty(type=LayerTreeNode)
bpy.types.Scene.layerListItem = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=LayerTreeItem)
bpy.types.Scene.layerList_index = IntProperty()

myNodes = bpy.types.Scene.layerListItem
myNodes.clear()
```

I have a problem executing the `myNodes.clear()` function as it gives me the error:

> **Blender error :   'tuple' object has no attribute 'clear'**

I tried the `add()` and the same error for that one as well.

Could any of you point me if I'm doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Hi. If you need to include code in the question, please include the code as text and not as images. This will make it easier for people to test your code and answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: [Tuples are immutable](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm)

Comment: @RayMairlot I changed and added code snippets

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I know tuples are immutable but I was following this code I found: 
https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-treelist-expanding-subelements-ui/1191260

and in there it has identified the PropertyGroup as a list. which has a clear() method.
I am unsure if I'm doing a mistake.

Comment: The code `bpy.types.Scene.foo = CollectionProperty()` wires this up as a property available to an instance of this class. (the call returns a tuple)  To use as expected you want an instance of the scene eg `bpy.context.scene.foo` not its class (type).  Have answered this before. Will look for it.

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you soo much for your comment. I figured it out after you. You are correct, in order to have it as a list type you need to assign the collectionProperty to 
`bpy.types.Scene.foo = CollectionProperty()`

but in order to have it as a list, 

`mynode = bpy.context.scene.foo`

Thank you.